# How to get rid of clojure/lang/RT.aset and clojure/lang/RT.intCast in clojure array processing?

Tags: arrays, performance, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I try to make multiplication of arrays of complex numbers in Clojure as fast as possible.

The chosen data structure is map of two elements, `:re` and `:im`, each is a Java native array of primitive `double` for low memory overhead.

According to http://clojure.org/reference/java_interop I used exact type specification for arrays of primitive types.

With these hints `aget` are converted into native array `dload` op, but there are two inefficiencies, exactly the counter of the loop is not `int` but `long`, so every time an array is indexed the counter is converted to `int` using a call to `clojure/lang/RT.intCast`. And also `aset` are not converted into native ops but into calls to `clojure/lang/RT.aset`.

One more inefficiency is checkcast. It checks every loop that the arrays are actually arrays of double.

The result is running time of this Clojure code is 30% more than that of the equivalent Java code (not including startup time). Can this function be rewritten in Clojure so that it works faster?

Clojure code, the function to optimize is `multiply-complex-arrays`.

```
(def size 65536)

(defn get-zero-complex-array
    []
    {:re (double-array size)
     :im (double-array size)})

(defn multiply-complex-arrays
    [a b]
    (let [
        a-re-array (doubles (get a :re))
        a-im-array (doubles (get a :im))
        b-re-array (doubles (get b :re))
        b-im-array (doubles (get b :im))
        res-re-array (double-array size)
        res-im-array (double-array size)
        ]
        (loop [i (int 0) size (int size)]
            (if (< i size)
                (let [
                    a-re (aget a-re-array i)
                    a-im (aget a-im-array i)
                    b-re (aget b-re-array i)
                    b-im (aget b-im-array i)
                    ]
                    (aset res-re-array i (- (* a-re b-re) (* a-im b-im)))
                    (aset res-im-array i (+ (* a-re b-im) (* b-re a-im)))
                    (recur (unchecked-inc i) size))
                {:re res-re-array :im res-im-array}))))

(let [
    res (loop [i (int 0) a (get-zero-complex-array)]
            (if (< i 30000)
                (recur (inc i) (multiply-complex-arrays a a))
                a))
    ]
    (println (aget (get res :re) 0)))
```

The java assembly generated for the main loop of `multiply-complex-arrays` is

```
  91: lload         8
  93: lload         10
  95: lcmp
  96: ifge          216
  99: aload_2
 100: checkcast     #51                 // class "[D"
 103: lload         8
 105: invokestatic  #46                 // Method clojure/lang/RT.intCast:(J)I
 108: daload
 109: dstore        12
 111: aload_3
 112: checkcast     #51                 // class "[D"
 115: lload         8
 117: invokestatic  #46                 // Method clojure/lang/RT.intCast:(J)I
 120: daload
 121: dstore        14
 123: aload         4
 125: checkcast     #51                 // class "[D"
 128: lload         8
 130: invokestatic  #46                 // Method clojure/lang/RT.intCast:(J)I
 133: daload
 134: dstore        16
 136: aload         5
 138: checkcast     #51                 // class "[D"
 141: lload         8
 143: invokestatic  #46                 // Method clojure/lang/RT.intCast:(J)I
 146: daload
 147: dstore        18
 149: aload         6
 151: checkcast     #51                 // class "[D"
 154: lload         8
 156: invokestatic  #46                 // Method clojure/lang/RT.intCast:(J)I
 159: dload         12
 161: dload         16
 163: dmul
 164: dload         14
 166: dload         18
 168: dmul
 169: dsub
 170: invokestatic  #55                 // Method clojure/lang/RT.aset:([DID)D
 173: pop2
 174: aload         7
 176: checkcast     #51                 // class "[D"
 179: lload         8
 181: invokestatic  #46                 // Method clojure/lang/RT.intCast:(J)I
 184: dload         12
 186: dload         18
 188: dmul
 189: dload         16
 191: dload         14
 193: dmul
 194: dadd
 195: invokestatic  #55                 // Method clojure/lang/RT.aset:([DID)D
 198: pop2
 199: lload         8
 201: lconst_1
 202: ladd
 203: lload         10
 205: lstore        10
 207: lstore        8
 209: goto          91
```

Java code:

```
class ComplexArray {

    static final int SIZE = 1 << 16;

    double re[];

    double im[];

    ComplexArray(double re[], double im[]) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }

    static ComplexArray getZero() {
        return new ComplexArray(new double[SIZE], new double[SIZE]);
    }

    ComplexArray multiply(ComplexArray second) {
        double resultRe[] = new double[SIZE];
        double resultIm[] = new double[SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            double aRe = this.re[i];
            double aIm = this.im[i];
            double bRe = second.re[i];
            double bIm = second.im[i];
            resultRe[i] = aRe * bRe - aIm * bIm;
            resultIm[i] = aRe * bIm + bRe * aIm;
        }
        return new ComplexArray(resultRe, resultIm);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ComplexArray a = getZero();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
            a = a.multiply(a);
        }
        System.out.println(a.re[0]);
    }
}
```

Assembly of the same loop in Java code:

```
  13: iload         4
  15: ldc           #5                  // int 65536
  17: if_icmpge     92
  20: aload_0
  21: getfield      #2                  // Field re:[D
  24: iload         4
  26: daload
  27: dstore        5
  29: aload_0
  30: getfield      #3                  // Field im:[D
  33: iload         4
  35: daload
  36: dstore        7
  38: aload_1
  39: getfield      #2                  // Field re:[D
  42: iload         4
  44: daload
  45: dstore        9
  47: aload_1
  48: getfield      #3                  // Field im:[D
  51: iload         4
  53: daload
  54: dstore        11
  56: aload_2
  57: iload         4
  59: dload         5
  61: dload         9
  63: dmul
  64: dload         7
  66: dload         11
  68: dmul
  69: dsub
  70: dastore
  71: aload_3
  72: iload         4
  74: dload         5
  76: dload         11
  78: dmul
  79: dload         9
  81: dload         7
  83: dmul
  84: dadd
  85: dastore
  86: iinc          4, 1
  89: goto          13
```

Comment: Why won't you just use Java implementation from Clojure?

Comment: @OlegTheCat it is possible, I just wander if there is an ideomatic way to write such Clojure code that Clojure compiler creates optimal code.

Comment: @OlegTheCat interesting quote is "the resulting code is exactly the same speed" from http://clojure.org/reference/java_interop . I wоnder if that example is the rule (and array processing in Clojure can be efficient) or an exception.

Comment: @FyodorMenshikov Could you detail the specific steps you're using to get the assembly you've given in your question?

Comment: @FyodorMenshikov Have you tried using [`aset-double`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/aset-double) instead of [`aset`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/aset)?

Comment: @SamEstep changing `aset` to `aset-double` makes the program slower (!) 32 (!) times.

Comment: @SamEstep The specific steps to get the assembly: 1. `lein new app tmp` 2. Edit tmp/src/tmp/code.clj - place `def size`, `defn get-zero-complex-array` and `defn multiply-complex-arrays` between `(:gen-class))` and `(defn -main`. 3. `lein uberjar` 4. extract tmp/core$multiply_complex_arrays.class from target/uberjar/tmp-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 5. `javap -p -c core$multiply_complex_arrays >src`

Comment: `(set! *unchecked-math* true)` will convert  the `intCast` calls to `l2i` instructions

Comment: @sw1nn Thank you, the best answer so far! `l2i` in assembly and Clojure program time went from 1.34 of Java time to just 1.22.

Comment: @sw1nn Is `(set! *unchecked-math* true)` a global setting? How can it be applied to just one function or even just one loop?

Comment: @sw1nn I realized that there is one more inefficiency in the assembly generated by Clojure. It is checkcast. It checks every time in the loop that the arrays are actually arrays of double. Could this check be moved before the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you benchmarking this code? I recommend using something like criterium or at least doing many executions before comparing times. Things like the checkcast should get optimized out by the JIT when it's warm enough. I also recommend using latest JVM, -server, and -XX:+AggressiveOpts.

Generally I find it's better to not try to force Clojure to use ints in loops - instead embrace longs as the loop counter, use `(set! *unchecked-math* true)`, and let Clojure downcast the longs to ints when indexing into the array. While this seems like extra work, my impression on modern hardware/JVM/JIT is that the difference is a lot less than you expect (as you're mostly working with 64-bit integers anyways). Also, it looks like you are carrying size as a loop variable but it never changes - maybe you were doing that to avoid type mismatch with i, but I would just let size (as a long) prior to the loop and do long increments and compares on i instead.

Sometimes you can reduce the checkcasts by let'ing things prior to the loop. While it is easy to eyeball the code and say when they aren't needed, the compiler doesn't really do any analysis of this and leaves it to the JIT to optimize things (which it generally is pretty good at, or which doesn't actually matter in 99% of your code).

```
(set! *unchecked-math* :warn-on-boxed)

(def ^long ^:const size 65536)

(defn get-zero-complex-array []
  {:re (double-array size)
   :im (double-array size)})

(defn multiply-complex-arrays [a b]
  (let [a-re-array (doubles (get a :re))
        a-im-array (doubles (get a :im))
        b-re-array (doubles (get b :re))
        b-im-array (doubles (get b :im))
        res-re-array (double-array size)
        res-im-array (double-array size)
        s (long size)]
    (loop [i 0]
      (if (< i s)
        (let [a-re (aget a-re-array i)
              a-im (aget a-im-array i)
              b-re (aget b-re-array i)
              b-im (aget b-im-array i)]
          (aset res-re-array i (- (* a-re b-re) (* a-im b-im)))
          (aset res-im-array i (+ (* a-re b-im) (* b-re a-im)))
          (recur (inc i)))
        {:re res-re-array :im res-im-array}))))

(defn compute []
  (let [res (loop [i 0 a (get-zero-complex-array)]
              (if (< i 30000)
                (recur (inc i) (multiply-complex-arrays a a))
                a))]
    (aget (get res :re) 0)))
```

Comment: After using `*unchecked-math*` time went from 1.34 java to 1.22 java, after moving `size` out of loop and recur into let (2 lines upper than in your suggestion to use it in double-array), time went to 1.17 java and with `^long ^:const` and `i` of type `long` time went to 1.15 java. Alex, thank you for valuable suggestions.

Comment: I measure wall time using output of `time` program under Windows. I run 5 times and get median. To get multiple of Java time I subtract time to perform 30000 loops and time to perform 1 loop in Java and in Clojure and then divide Clojure difference by Java difference.

Comment: The problem is related to competitive programming so the code have no time to run more than 10 seconds, so I do not measure it after few minutes of warm up.

Comment: Is `(set! *unchecked-math* :warn-on-boxed)` a global setting? How can it be applied to just one function or even just one loop?

Comment: `*unchecked-math*` is a dynamic variable, so it has both a root binding (false) and can be set on a per-thread basis (here). It cannot be applied to just one function or loop unless you make a macro that sets and resets the value around a function.

Comment: How can `*unchecked-math*` be set on a per-thread basis if Clojure not interprets code but compiles it into bytecode? In bytecode of a function the checks are either present or not. It looks rather like compiler pragma in C++ so its scope probably should be static in nature. Is there any in-depth documentation or tutorial on `*unchecked-math*` ? Can `*unchecked-math*` be applied without "set!" but to specific aget's and aset's?